# Adding data from customer_entity_varchar to order grid magento

Tags: magento, grid

I am trying to add 'accountno' field to order grid from customer_entity_varchar table. To achieve this I changed _prepareCollection() method in Grid.php like this:

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

           $customerEntityVarchar = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar');

            $collection->getSelect()->join(array(
                'customer_entity_varchar_table'=>$customerEntityVarchar), 
                '`main_table`.`customer_id`=`customer_entity_varchar_table`.`entity_id`
                    AND `customer_entity_varchar_table`.`attribute_id`=122', 
                array('accountno' => 'value')); 

            print_r($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
            $this->setCollection($collection);
            return parent::_prepareCollection();

    }
```

> In attribute_id`=122' 122 is the attribute_id of`accountno`

When I print_r the select query and execute it in phpmyadmin, it gets me the accurate results back but when I try to add Column to grid in _prepareColumns() method, it shows the field blank.
My _prepareColumns method looks like this:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
         $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

          $this->addColumnAfter('accountno', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Account No'),
                'index' => 'accountno',       
            ), 'real_order_id');
//rest of the code here
      }
```

Comment: Which Class are you extending? Is it `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` or `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`?

Have you tried searching in _Account No_ for a specific value? Will it throw a DB-Error?